# Not able to trigger matSortChange event manually,getting error directive undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test in angular app. I  want to manually trigger matSort directive for matsortchange event. Also I try to change the attribute values like matsortdirection from asc to desc etc or on click/matsortevent I try to print to console. I am not able to this

```
template.html
<table id=tabmat_1 matSort (matSortChange)="sortData(i, $event)" matSortActive="enddate" matSortDirection="desc" matSortDisableClear >

@Directive({

    selector:'matSort',
    host:{'(matSortChange)':'onClick()'}
})
export class DemoClass{

  matSortActive="startdate";
  matSortDirection="asc";
  onClick(){
    console.log('matsort trigger worked!!!');
  }
}

  let matsort1=fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(DemoClass))
  let matsortdirective=matsort1[0].injector.get(DemoClass);
  matsort1[0].triggerEventHandler('matSortChange',null);

  console.log(matsort1)//I want to print here, matsort trigger worked!!!
  })
```

Comment: no one is answering my question, please someone help me

Comment: I commented schema:no_errors and then added my custom directive class to testbed declaration array it works